# Check if resource exists

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check if a resource key exists before get it from resources.
I use TemplateControl.GetGlobalResourceObject to get the resource.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetGlobalResourceObject` returns `object` type. You can always check if it is `null` before you cast it (to a string for example) and use it in subsequent logic.

Be careful that `(string)TemplateControl.GetGlobalResourceObject` will `throw` an `InvalidCastException` that needs to be handled.

For reference:
[TemplateControl.GetGlobalResourceObject Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153593.aspx)

Comment: If you use `TemplateControl.GetGlobalResourceObject(...) as string`, then you don't have to deal with `InvalidCastException` and can just check if the result is `null`.